# iOS 6 iPhone 5 App NOT fullscreen in Phonegap Build?

Tags: android, ios, cordova, fullscreen, phonegap-build

Hey all i am running my app and it seems to be fullscreen on my android device but it has the black bars on top/bottom on the iPhone 5.... What settings do i need to set for those to work?

The way my app looks on my android is this:

[image]

And the way it looks on my iPhone 5 is this:

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For your app add the default image for the iphone 5, `Default-568h@2x.png`. That automatically gets rid of the bars.

Answer (score 1):

to give a bit more detail, add this line, and the corresponding image to your config.xml file:

```
<gap:splash src="images/Default-568h@2x.png" gap:platform="ios" width="640" height="1136" />
```

Answer (score 1):

It happens also when **Launch Screen File** is not specified.
Go to

Target Setting --> General --> App Icons and Launch Images -->  Launch Screen File --> (select) Main.Storyboard.

Done!